# View Full File Name in Project View Unity

Tags: unity

Is there any way to view the full name of a file in Unity Project view without having to click on it?

This picture sums up my frustration:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick way is to switch to a "detailed" view of the files, by sliding the zoom slider to the left:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Use two project views

(An improvement on [Galandil](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/100419/galandil)'s answer)

Open two project views, one zoomed out to list ("detailed") view and the other in some larger convenient size (thumbnails view):

[image: Two project views, one in detailed view]

When an asset is selected in one project view, it is also focused/highlighted in the other.

Based on this [Unity forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/truncated-filename-in-project-window.405866/) by user [thomascrozelonpro](https://forum.unity.com/members/thomascrozelonpro.8060819/).

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. Might need a 4K screen for that. Good thing I got one.

Comment: @AzulShiva - that actually works perfectly with standard (1920x1080) resolution too. (Good for you on the 4k screen btw ;-) )

Comment: I find a better way of doing this is to set the "detailed" view to use the one column layout (right click on the "project" tab to choose), which makes it much more compact